# Uninstalling nordvpn

Tags: sudo, uninstall, vpn

When I run

```
sudo apt-get remove nordvpn
```

and when I try

```
whereis nordvpn
```

or

```
find -name "*nord*"
```

nothing shows up
These commands are indicating that I don't have nord installed on my system,
However every time I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It will try to connect to nordvpn

```
[Connecting to repo.nordvpn.com (10.10.34.35)]
```

which is really annoying, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said anything about your version/flavour of Ubuntu so making some assumptions:

Run `software-properties-gtk`, click `Other Software` tab, find any Nord VPN references and un-check or remove them, then press `Close` button.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "purge"

```
sudo apt purge nordvpn*
```

also don't forget to remove from dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -P nordvpn
sudo dpkg -P nordvpn-release
```

lastly, if you did add your user to nordvpn group using "usermod", you can remove that too.

Comment: Before just blindly deleting something I would contact the vendor and ask them for the PROPER way to remove their software.

Comment: @David [here](https://support.nordvpn.com/General-info/1047410452/How-to-uninstall-NordVPN-software.htm) the vendor described PROPERLY.